# Multiple delete in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, multi-table-delete

DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ConditionID=?ConditionID;

```
DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE ConditionID=?ConditionID;

DELETE FROM Table3 WHERE ConditionID=?ConditionID;
```

ConditionID is a column present in Table1,Table2,Table3, instead of running 3 times individually, is there a way to run all the three in a single query (in mysql)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `ConditionID` is the same for all the three tables, you should be able to use the [Multiple Table Delete Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE Table1, Table2, Table3
FROM   Table1
JOIN   Table2 ON (Table2.ConditionID = Table1.ConditionID)
JOIN   Table3 ON (Table3.ConditionID = Table2.ConditionID)
WHERE  Table1.ConditionID = ?;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (id int, ConditionID int);
CREATE TABLE Table2 (id int, ConditionID int);
CREATE TABLE Table3 (id int, ConditionID int);

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1, 100);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (2, 100);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (3, 200);

INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1, 100);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (2, 200);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (3, 300);

INSERT INTO Table3 VALUES (1, 100);
INSERT INTO Table3 VALUES (2, 100);
INSERT INTO Table3 VALUES (3, 100);
```

Result:

```
DELETE Table1, Table2, Table3
FROM   Table1
JOIN   Table2 ON (Table2.ConditionID = Table1.ConditionID)
JOIN   Table3 ON (Table3.ConditionID = Table2.ConditionID)
WHERE  Table1.ConditionID = 100;

SELECT * FROM Table1;
+------+-------------+
| id   | ConditionID |
+------+-------------+
|    3 |         200 |
+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM Table2;
+------+-------------+
| id   | ConditionID |
+------+-------------+
|    2 |         200 |
|    3 |         300 |
+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM Table3;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Excellent,outstanding approach.

Comment: Not sur it's a good solution. If an id is not in `table2` but the same id is in `table1` and `table3`, will rows in  `table1` and `table3` be deleted ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your schema looks like, but if you use InnoDB, or a similar table engine for your tables and you have foreign keys, you can set conditions that will cause derived entries to be deleted when a parent entry is deleted.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html for more info on that.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. `ConditionID` is separate in each one—just because it has the same name doesn't mean it's the same column. If you fully qualify the names, you'll be able to see it better:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.ConditionID=?ConditionID;

DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ConditionID=?ConditionID;

DELETE FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.ConditionID=?ConditionID;
```

Comment: I want to delete Id value of 100 from the 3 tables. DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ConditionID=100;

DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE ConditionID=100;

DELETE FROM Table3 WHERE ConditionID=100; instead of calling 3 times, is there in a single approach using some joins?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete rows from multiple tables by just using mysql "delete" query.Consider,you've two tables profile and books.

Profile table consists,

- id
- name

books table consists,

- pid
- book
- price

You can delete records from these two table for particular id by using this query,

```
delete profile,books from profile,books where profile.id=18 and profile.id=books.pid;
```